# Moodle The module MYMODULE does not define the standard capability

Tags: php, moodle

I am developing a module for Moodle. I've achieve to install and instantiate it in a course. The problem is that, in "edit mode" enabled, moodle me out the following message:

```
The module mymodule does not define the standard capability mod/mymodule:addinstance

    line 3451 of \course\lib.php: call to debugging()
    line 1899 of \course\lib.php: call to course_allowed_module()
    line 1767 of \course\lib.php: call to get_module_metadata()
    line 682 of \course\format\renderer.php: call to print_section_add_menus()
    line 49 of \course\format\weeks\format.php: call to format_section_renderer_base->print_multiple_section_page()
    line 276 of \course\view.php: call to require()
```

In `/mod/mymodule/db/access.php` file I have the following code:

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$capabilities = array(
    'mod/mymodule:view' => array(
        'captype' => 'read',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_MODULE,
        'legacy' => array(
            'guest' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'student' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'teacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'editingteacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'admin' => CAP_ALLOW
        )
    ),

    'mod/mymodule:submit' => array(
        'riskbitmask' => RISK_SPAM,
        'captype' => 'write',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_MODULE,
        'legacy' => array(
            'student' => CAP_ALLOW
        )
    ),
);
```

I am a beginner in module development for Moodle. I have read the following documentation:

- http://docs.moodle.org/dev/NEWMODULE_Adding_capabilities
- http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Access_API

But I have not clarified anything.

**EDITED 2013-04-28**

I have added this code to my access.php file ($capabilities array):

```
'mod/mymodule:myaddinstance' => array(
                'captype' => 'write',
                'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_SYSTEM,
                'archetypes' => array(
                        'user' => CAP_ALLOW
                ),

                'clonepermissionsfrom' => 'moodle/my:manageblocks'
        ),

        'mod/mymodule:addinstance' => array(
                'riskbitmask' => RISK_SPAM | RISK_XSS,

                'captype' => 'write',
                'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_MODULE,
                'archetypes' => array(
                        'editingteacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
                        'manager' => CAP_ALLOW
                ),

                'clonepermissionsfrom' => 'moodle/site:manageblocks'
        ),
```

But it doesn't works.

Comment: None of the lines in your error message mention `access.php`.  Perhaps the problem is in `view.php`?

Comment: I do not think the problem is in file view.php, because I get this message in the list of course activities, not in the view of mymodule. When I enter in mymodule view (view.php) do not visualize any problems.

Comment: Are you using moodle 2.4 or above?

Comment: Sorry. The version is 2.4.3+ (Build: 20130328)

Comment: Then I think I've found the problem; see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first it seemed like a strange error message, since it mentions `mod/mymodule:addinstance` but you don't have that in your code.  But on closer inspection, that seems to be the problem - moodle expects you to define `addinstance` but you don't!

This is apparently a new behavior from 2.4 onwards: http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks#db.2Faccess.php

The solution seems to be to add `addinstance` (and possibly `myaddinstance`, depending on your settings and implementation) to your `$capabilities` array.

Comment: Reading your solution,I add this to my access.php:

'mod/mymodule:myaddinstance' => array(
    'captype' => 'write',
    'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_SYSTEM,
    'archetypes' => array(
      'user' => CAP_ALLOW
    ),
  
    'clonepermissionsfrom' => 'moodle/my:manageblocks'
  ),
  
  'mod/mymodule:addinstance' => array(
    'riskbitmask' => RISK_SPAM | RISK_XSS,
  
    'captype' => 'write',
    'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_MODULE,
    'archetypes' => array(
      'editingteacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
      'manager' => CAP_ALLOW
    ),
  
    'clonepermissionsfrom' => 'moodle/site:manageblocks'
  ),

Comment: Ok, It works!. The problem was that, after updating the access.php file, I did not change the version number in the file version.php to update the module and new capabilities are included. http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Modules#access.php